# String handling from Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am new to programming. I have a file in which i have text like this

```
File.Txt
{
 "query" : "*",
 "start_time" : "20170322T090000.000Z",
 "end_time" : "20170322T100000.000Z"
}
```

I want to extract the value query, start time and end time from this file and store these values in powershell variables.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any attempt to write the PS script on your own?

Comment: [Convert JSON File to PowerShell Object](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/23/powertip-convert-json-file-to-powershell-object/)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Get-Content -Path 'file.txt' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

It assumes that the content in file.txt is valid JSON format.